# Using Active Directory to prevent user from performing certain action in a window application

Tags: c#, active-directory

I am currently experimenting on active directory whereby i have this window form with two buttons, Btn1 and Btn2. In the active directory, i already set up the two users, User1 and User2.

Now in this form, i will have four scenarios here where,
a)User1 click on Btn1. (Message Prompt successful click).
b)User1 click on Btn2. (Message Prompt, no authorized access).
c)User2 click on Btn1. (Message Prompt, no authorized access).
d)User2 click on Btn2. (Message Prompt, succesful click)>

What will be the most recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `WindowsIdentity` & `WindowsPrincipal` class. How, I implemented something similar was by putting the users into AD group. So User1 is in for example 'Admin Group' and this is checked either on form load, or any event.. like this:

```
WindowsIdentity user = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal prince = new WindowsPrincipal(user);
if(prince.IsInRole(@"Admin Group"))
{
  // the user is in admin so.. he is authorized!!
} else 
{
   // show error message
}
```